# Axillary curve line for a path in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

There is a noisy image as `fig a`. by reducing image noise finally a `smoothspline` could fit to the dots as shown in `fig b`. now it's desire to find two axillary lines both side of the original line like offset (in this case it's better to say outline). how can these lines(yellow and green) position be found? 
if there is a simple straight line it would be easy but here is spline.
any idea would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What are the outlines defined by? A constant vertical distance to (b), a constant perpendicular distance to (b), a scalar multiplication of (b)...

Comment: The main propose of this post is calculating the intensity of both of axillary lines and comparing their normalized difference with a threshold to detect which part of the original curve is inside of the shape. to clarify it, it's better to say it's not just a `vertical distance`(thanks for asking it) cause it would be complex  shape. I don't have any idea about how would `perpendicular distance` or `scalar multiplications`  be in this case but i explained why it's desire to find this axillary lines.. thanks @Wolfie for  spending time on this post.

Comment: Your comment hasn't answered the point of my question, I understand how you want to *use* the lines, but how do you want to *calculate* where the lines are? You should be posting code here which has a problem, this isn't a code-writing/guessing site... See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you wanted:

```
% generate random curve
xy = randi(5,[2,3]);
t = 1:3;
tq = linspace(1,3,100);
xyq = interp1(t',xy',tq','spline');
xx = xyq(:,1);
yy = xyq(:,2);
% get curve's approx. angle in each point
theta = atan2(xyq(2:end,2) - xyq(1:end-1,2),xyq(2:end,1) - xyq(1:end-1,1));
theta(end+1) = theta(end);
% add or subtract 90 degrees to get downward or upward normal angle
tp1 = theta + pi/2;
tp2 = theta - pi/2;
% distance from original curve
d = 0.1;
% compute x-y additions
[xa1,ya1] = pol2cart(tp1,d);
[xa2,ya2] = pol2cart(tp2,d);
% plot curve and its axillary lines
plot(xx,yy,'g')
hold on
plot(xyq(:,1) + xa1,xyq(:,2) + ya1,'b')
plot(xyq(:,1) + xa2,xyq(:,2) + ya2,'r')
legend('orig.','axil._1','axil._2');
```

and you get this:
[image]